# Architecture for RabbitMQ in tandem with AngularJS/.NET Web API application

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, reporting-services, rabbitmq

So I have a SPA (single page application) with AngularJS as the front-end and .NET Web API the back-end (C#). I have a requirement to generate SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) reports upon some user action, i.e. select some data and press a button. Here is a rough illustration of my existing architecture:

```
FRONT END                 BACK END                  SSRS Report
==========                =========                 ===========
**AngularJS Web page**-->**.NET Web API controller**-->**Intermediary class (passes arguments to report)** -->**Generate report and save to file**
```

This works, but the problem is while the reports are being generated the application has to sit there and wait for them to finish and in the meantime the user can't do anything. If there are many reports to create, 100+ for example, it can take upwards of a minute or two, which is not acceptable for me.

So this is where RabbitMQ comes in. The idea I have is for the .NET Web API controller to send a message to a server, once the server receives it a call is performed to the intermediary class above, which generates the report, then a response is sent back to the client letting them know the report has been generated. I think I would need to use the RPC scenario for that so I've done the corresponding tutorial on the RabbitMQ site and it seems straightforward enough.

What I don't know though, and this is what my question is about, is how to start-up a client and a server from a .NET Web API application. Frankly I am a bit lost at the moment as this is my first real experience with any sort of messaging and I am not quite sure how to approach it, architecture wise. If I can get a detailed picture in my head of how the whole thing would work I can code it from there, but at this point I am having trouble visualizing how to structure the application.

So, questions:

1. How do i start a RabbitMQ server and client from a .NET Web API controller? Should the server and client be class libraries or console applications, or something else entirely?
2. Is the architecture I am envisioning going to work or is there a better approach?
3. Any general advice about how to approach what I am trying to accomplish would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. RabbitMQ server is not something you start from controller - it's always running. From controller you send a message to rabbitmq server. On the other side, another application (windows service, console application, or even mono service on linux) listens for those messages and handles them. RabbitMQ server only manages sending messages between endpoints. In your case, application that handles messages from your controller is also always running (so reasonable to make it windows service).
2. Such architecture will work yes. RabbitMQ might be an overkill though - it's more for multi-server, high load scenarios. If you have low load and all applications are on the same server - you can use other tools (like [hangfire.io](http://hangfire.io), MSMQ, or even just run background tasks in the web server process as another answer suggests). If simple tool might do your job - why not.
3. Don't hold connection from client (browser) to server for the whole time when report is generating. Just put task in rabbit queue for processing (or otherwise start generating report) and return. Then either poll periodically from client if the job is done, or (better) notify client via websocket connection. This is of course if report generation can take some time (more than 30 seconds say).

Update: a bit more about overall architecture.

- RabbitMQ server is running as a windows service, starts together with Windows.
- When you receive request for report generation via web api - you put GenerateReport message with all information required, then you return (not waiting for the report to be generated). If you store your reports in database, so they are persistent - create a record in database about report request. Otherwise - persist information about pending report in memory (so that you known that X reports are being generated at the moment). In ideal case you also have persistent connection between client and server via web sockets. If that is the case - you will notify user about report generation state in real time. Otherwise - user will have to poll server from time to time about that.
- On the other side there is windows service written by you, it also starts together with Windows server. It listens for GenerateReport message and starts generation. There can be multiple such services, or you can have multiple subscriptions inside one service - this will distribute workload between multiple services evenly. During report generation - post ReportProgress messages. When done - update report in database (if you persist them) and publish ReportDone message. Background thread in Web Api service listens for such messages. If you have websockets connection - you just pass those messages over to client so he sees report generation progress at realtime. Otherwise - update database or in-memory structure so that when next time client will poll about report state - you have something to return.
- If something went wrong - no problem (if you persist report in database). On startup your generating service will check in database if there are pending reports and generate them. If client disconnected during report generation (from web site) - still no problem, when he returns report will be ready and can be served from database. If web api service crashed - still no problem.

Comment: 1. @Evk , would what you are describing be the equivalent of the Remote Procedure Call (RPC) pattern wherein there is a Client and a Server and the former sends messages to the latter and then receives messages (with the result) back? This is described in more detail here: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-dotnet.html.

Comment: 2. If so, would what you refer to as “another application listens for those messages and handles them” correspond to a Client in an RPC pattern? Also, you say the RabbitMQ server is always running and even though it should not be started from a controller, something has to start it. How does that work? Who starts the server? In other words, let’s say I code the server, like in the example on the RabbitMQ site above. What do I do with it after that? I assume I have to deploy it somewhere and configure it somehow so it is always running. Same question for the Client.

Comment: @user452103 rabbit is just message bus (intermediary, proxy) between one or more applications. In your case one application is your asp.net web api service. Another application is what generates reports (for example - separate console or windows service application). If you use RPC pattern, application A (web api) sends a message to application B(windows service) asking to generate a report. Then it _waits_ until application B will send a message back with the results of operation. As for who starts Rabbit. On windows you can run rabbit as a service - then it starts together with Windows.

Comment: @user452103 some more things. First, because you are new with rabbit - better use a wrapper around rabbitmq api (this one is good: http://easynetq.com/). It hides many complicated things about rabbitmq and will make it easy for you to get things done. Second - better not use RPC pattern in your case (see third point in my answer).

Comment: thanks for the easynetq suggestion. That looks like it'd be useful. As for the pattern, are you saying a disadvantage of RPC for my case would be that it would connection between client and server the entire time? And if not RPC, then what pattern would be better? Maybe a simpler Sender-Receiver pattern wherein a sender sends a single message (one report to generate, for example) and a receiver receives it and makes a call to the report generation API? Or perhaps a Work queue where tasks are distributed among multiple workers? Keep in mind I could have many reports (300-1000).

Comment: 2. And ideally I would like to know when each report is generated, so I can give the user feedback about what is going on.

Comment: @user452103 I've expanded my answer a bit to answer your questions.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the new `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem` that was introduced in .Net 4.5 before switching to RabbitMQ

```
HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(cancellationToken =>
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        // Generate report and save to file
    }, cancellationToken);
});
```

Comment: Nope, I have not. That's the first time I've heard of it. What exactly does it do?

Comment: "Schedules a task which can run in the background, independent of any request." and [here's a blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2014/06/04/queuebackgroundworkitem-to-reliably-schedule-and-run-background-processes-in-asp-net/) with more details.

Comment: Sounds like it has some serious limitations though. For example: "If you have so many items queued that they can’t be completed in 90 seconds, the ASP.NET runtime will unload the AppDomain without waiting for the work items to finish." That's kind of a deal breaker for me as I could potentially have so many reports that they'd easily take more than 90 seconds to generate.